# int i=99 is working however int i = 099 not working

Tags: java, int, runtime-error, runtimeexception

In Java, I noticed that when I write

```
int i = 99;
```

it works fine. However when I say

```
int i = 099;
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
```

In my IDE, I see a red dot saying  `integer number too large: 099`.

Why this is not getting compiled?  Isn't 099 is equivalent to 99?

Comment: `099` is assumed to be an octal number in Java. [More details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any leading `0`s will make Java interprets the number as octal number. So, `010` is actually `8`.

```
System.out.println(010);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
8
```

---

And as you know, `8` and `9` are not allowed in an octal number.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yeah, most of Java's syntax is inherited from C :)

Answer (score 6):

That's an octal number.  Octal numbers are prefixed with `0` to set them apart from other values such as decimal and hexadecimal.